# Rest Controller method not getting called in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I am implementing rest webservice via a spring boot application.

POM

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.myCompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>services</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>REST Services</name>
    <description>REST Services</description>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>   
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

application.properties

```
server.port=8082
server.contexPath=/services
logging.level.org.springframework.web = DEBUG
logging.level.com.myCompany= INFO
logging.file = ../logs/services.log
```

Application launcher class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Controller

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class AccountRestController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AccountRestController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value="/account", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public void createAccount(){
        logger.info("ACCOUNT METHOD CALLED");
    }
}
```

I see **Did not find handler method for [/services/account]** message in the console when I fire http://localhost:8082/services/account URL in the browser as shown below

```
2018-02-06 08:30:42.868 DEBUG 7532 --- [http-nio-8082-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /services/account
2018-02-06 08:30:42.868 DEBUG 7532 --- [http-nio-8082-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/services/account]
2018-02-06 08:30:42.869 DEBUG 7532 --- [http-nio-8082-exec-3] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Matching patterns for request [/services/account] are [/**]
2018-02-06 08:30:42.869 DEBUG 7532 --- [http-nio-8082-exec-3] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : URI Template variables for request [/services/account] are {}
```

I dont see message - ACCOUNT METHOD CALLED in the console meaning controller method is not getting invoked.Can you please let me know why createAccount() method not getting called ?
 Is controller class getting identified/scanned by Spring factory?
 What is causing this error?

Comment: are both classes in the same folder?

Comment: Typo on setting the contextPath, There is a T missing: `server.contextPath=/services`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please change `server.contexPath` to `server.contextPath`.

And try again, it should work as there's no extra `config` or code is there.

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-application-configuration

Answer (score 3):

1. Can you help us to capture your project structure? `AccountRestController` should be in the same package (or in sub-package) of `Application`. Like this: [image: Simple stupid project structure]
2. Did you check you log file? Does it has any log?

Comment: Mappings are not related to the project structure.

Answer (score 0):

Your server.contexPath should be server.contextPath. You missed a T in contexPath.

Answer (score 0):

there is no request mapping in your class level. After **@RestController** , There should be **@RequestMapping("/services/*)**

Comment: That's one way, true. He tried to change the general base-URL via the property `server.contextPath` so that should already add the "/service"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you misspelled that property, it should be server.contex**t**Path, not server.contexPath (w/o a 't') like in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller should be in the same package or in any subpackage of your main `SpringBootApplication` file.

If you want to include controllers present in either some other package or in a higher level then you can specifically mention that using `componentScan annotation.`

As shown in the below reference image, my login controller is not present in the same or subpackage of `StudentServicesApplication.java`. Hence I have specifically mentioned the package name of the controller to be considered using componentScan

[image]